# How to convert Char to Int in Haskell?

Tags: haskell, char, int

I need to convert a `Char` to an `Int` in Haskell? For example:

```
a = '\x2' -- a == 2
          -- type of a should be Char
b = charToInt a -- b == 2
                -- type of b should be Int
```

How can I achieve this?

Comment: Discover and use [hoogle](http://www.haskell.org/hoogle/?hoogle=Char+-%3E+Int).

Answer (score 30, accepted):

You can use the [`ord`](http://zvon.org/other/haskell/Outputchar/ord_f.html) function to convert a character to its integer (ordinal) representation.

[`chr`](http://zvon.org/other/haskell/Outputchar/chr_f.html) goes the other direction.

```
> ord '\x2'­
  => 2
> chr 97
  => 'a'
> ord (chr 42)
  => 42
```

Comment: just to add, you have to `import Char` or `import Data.Char` in order to use those

Answer (score 5):

You can use fromEnum or Data.Char.ord.

Comment: (fromEnum 'x') - (fromEnum '0') == x

Comment: @jpredham We have `digitToInt '9'` from `Data.Char` for that exact puprose